# Project an element returned with "$arrayElemAt"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Forgive me if I confuse some terminology here, but I'm performing a join operation in an aggregation using the '$lookup' operator as shown here:

```
db.collection('items').aggregate([{$match: {}},
{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'usr',
        localField: 'usr._id',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: '__usr'
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        info: 1,
        timestamp: 1,
        usr: {
            "$arrayElemAt": [ "$__usr", 0 ]
        }
    }
}], (err, result) => {
    res.json(result);
    db.close();
});
```

I'm performing a projection on the aggregation result, and I'm using '$arrayElemAt' to extract the single 'usr' match from the resulting array.
For obvious reasons, I don't want to return the entire 'usr' record which contains sensitive information.
What I'm looking to do is perform a projection on the element returned using the '$arrayElemAt' operation.
The only way I've been able to accomplish this is to use an additional projection of the original projection, like so:

```
db.collection('items').aggregate([{$match: {}},
{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'usr',
        localField: 'usr._id',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: '__usr'
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        info: 1,
        timestamp: 1,
        usr: {
            "$arrayElemAt": [ "$__usr", 0 ]
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        info: 1,
        timestamp: 1,
        usr: {
            "username": 1
        }
    }
}], (err, result) => {
    res.json(result);
    db.close();
});
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without the duplicated projection?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It looks like this is *still*, as of August 2018, the best way to accomplish the projection of a document joined via `$lookup` to a single embedded document and filter it's fields is still via a secondary `$project` pipeline stage. While the method shown by @styvane above *does* work, and is indeed very novel, it adds even more complexity to the pipeline so I'm hesitant to accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 11):

You can assign the `$arrayElemAt` returned value to a variable using the `$let` expression and use dot notation to access the subdocument field in the `in` expression.

```
"usr": {
    "$let": {
        "vars": { 
            "field": { 
                "$arrayElemAt": [ "$__usr", 0 ]
            }
        },
        "in": "$$field.username"
    }
```