# Project field in embedded document within embedded array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following query:

```
 cursor=self.postCol.aggregate([
      { "$graphLookup" : {
        "from": "pCol",
        "startWith": "$parent",
        "connectFromField": "parent",
        "connectToField": "_id",
        "as" : "parents"
        }
      },
      { "$project" : {
         "pValue": {
             "$cond": [
               { "$ne": [ "$pValue", [] ] },
               "$pValue",
               "$parents.0.pValue"
             ]
           }
         }
      }
    ])
```

so given then following records:

```
{"_id": 4, parent: "", "pValue": ["d"], fieldA: 9},
{"_id": 5, parent: 4, "pValue": [], fieldA:2},
{"_id": 6, parent: 4,"pValue": [], fieldA: 9}
```

I should get:

```
{"_id": 4, "pValue": ["d"]}
{"_id": 5, "pValue": ["d"]}
{"_id": 6, "pValue": ["d"]}
```

Instead I get:

```
{"_id": 4, "pValue": ["d"]}
{"_id": 5, "pValue": []}
{"_id": 6, "pValue": []}
```

The `$parents.0.pValue` isn't returning the right value for some reason which I don't understand. How can I select the field of `pValue` within the first element of the parents array?

I thought to use `{"$arrayElemAt": ["$parents",0]}` which will give me the embedded document but then how can I then get a field from that to be returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the else condition with below using `$let` operator.

```
 {
    $let: {
        vars: {
            obj: {
                "$arrayElemAt": ["$parents", 0]
            }
        },
        in: "$$obj.pValue"
    }
 }
```

Comment: It worked! Can't believe it took that much code :S Thank you Veeram! What does the double $$ mean?

Comment: That is notation for referring the variable declared inside let operator.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`$switch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/) operator and the [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let) operator to `$project` your field.

The `$let` variable operator let you assign a value to a variable which can be used in the "in" expression as shown in my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41058750/project-an-element-returned-with-arrayelemat).

With the `$switch` operator, we can [perform very clean case-statement.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494113/performing-case-statement-in-mongodb-aggregation-framework)

```
db.postCol.aggregate([
    { "$graphLookup": { 
        "from": "postCol",  
        "startWith": "$parent",  
        "connectFromField": "parent", 
        "connectToField": "_id",   
        "as" : "parents"           
    }}, 
    { "$project": { 
        "pValue": { 
            "$switch": { 
                "branches": [ 
                    { "case": { "$gt": [ { "$size": "$pValue"}, 0 ] },
                    "then": "$pValue" }
                ], 
                "default": { 
                    "$let": { 
                        "vars": { "p": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$parents", 0 ] }}, 
                        "in": "$$p.pValue" 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```